# how to duplicate the file in sharepoint designer - editform.aspx to dispform.aspx and newform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I've a list with 50 columns. I duplicated the Editform.aspx in sharepoint designer and make layout changes (styles, colors, tables etc.) call newEditform.aspx.

now I like to duplicated this editfrom.aspx to newNEWFORM.aspx and newDispform.aspx...

how can I do that... I've made the changes in the newNewForm.aspx => conrolmode="NEW" and controlmode="display" in newDispForm.aspx, but it doesn't work... it overrides the EDITFORM.ASPX.

I've also tried copying the code manually, but it get error code like it says webpart issue and guid number.

Coulplease advice the right manner to duplicate the newEditform.aspx and newNewForm.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three forms use fundamentally different controls. You can't just copy and rename the edit form. The Display form uses display controls, the New and the Edit form use data entry controls, and there are differences between the New and the Edit form for obvious reasons, too.

If you want to customise these forms, you will need to make the customisations in each form. There are no shortcuts.